# Scala: Http client read http response

Tags: scala, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using `httpClient` lib to do some `REST API` calls using scala. I am able to post the data.

I am using the following code to read the content. However, When I run on **Spark Databricks Cluster** it gives me an error.

```
 val entity = response.getEntity
    var content = ""
    if (entity != null) {
      val inputStream = entity.getContent
      content = io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).getLines.mkString
      inputStream.close()
    }
```

**Error**

> error: object Source is not a member of package io
> content = io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).getLines.mkString

is there a way I can fix this error, or a different way to read HTTP response content.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to `import scala.io.Source`

OR use the completed package name like this:

```
content = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).getLines.mkString
```